# Shortest way to fill a (Tree)Set with Integers?

Tags: java, set, treeset

if I want to make a (Tree)Set and fill it with 2000 Integers. To start with 0 then add 1,2,3,4...2000. Whats the best way?

I could do

```
Set set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
        set.add(0);
        set.add(1);
        set.add(2);
//...
```

or make a while with add(i);i++;

But is there a easier/shorter way?

Thank you!

Comment: 0..2000 inclusive is 2001 integers; which one did you want to leave out?

Answer (score 4):

Not really, there are no bob=[0...2000] shortcuts in Java.

```
Set set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
for(int i = 0; i <= 2000; ++i)
    set.add(i);
```

Comment: ok, this works too...but i tought something like "set.add(0...2000)". That would be awesome

Answer (score 0):

```
Set set = new TreeSet<Integer>();
// add Integers 0,1,...1999
for(int i=0;i<2000;i++){
  set.add(new Integer(i));
}
```